# Graphics driver crash - too many pixels as input?

Tags: c#, graphics, crash

I have an app where we are displaying on the earth/globe numerous data points which represent earthquakes along with location of occurance, the magnitude & color (red signifies major quake). Data is fed into the app from excel, and the app displays the globe and with the data points drawn on it. 
([see this page](http://www.layerscape.org/Home/ExcelAddInHelp) down below at - "Tutorial One: Earthquake Data" - its in step 6. Yellow, white, green are some data points. If you observe closely we see that the size of dots are different for different colors / magnitude. As magnitude gets higher, color and size of dot increases. Red (not seen in image), is significant in magnitude and its dot is much larger than what was seen). Data is basically of the form, data points and its magnitudes. Small magnitude has a small dot as a data point on screen. Larger magnitude has a bigger dot.

When too many such data points (like a million) are fed as input, the driver seems to crash and it results in a BSOD. (I have experienced this crash when the data points are concentrated around a certain point.) When the data is displayed initially with million or so points concentrated around a small region, we see all of the million or so points as a small dot, since initial state is zoomed out to see the whole globe. As we zoom-in, the million or so data points, now get drawn on a larger surface area on the screen. The response of the zooming-in slows down, and eventually if we continuue to zoom it crashes. This is data specific (more points combined with its magnitude can crash).
I was told this is a rendering issue, and that too many data points are being fed for graphics to draw. Is it?

A possible solution we had explored is when feeding data to our app (data source is excel), we check at the source level and calculate somehow if the data can cause a crash. But this works for a specific graphic card. I would like to know if it is possible to have a *dynamic solution* based on the data and compare if graghics has the capability to draw. (different users different cards and hence different capability). If yes, what could i do?

Comment: Good question. I would like to see the answer.